# How to Call All Pictures with the Same ID

Tags: php, mysql

How do I write an SQL query in PHP using an id in the select clause?

I am working on a simple script where registred users can add offers...

My script have two tabeles so far..

Table 1 > Text entries such as title, description, category etc...
Table 2 > Photos...

Structure of Tables:

Table 1: >

```
id     offer_title      offer_description   
105    Selling dog..    I am selling dog..
```

Table 2: >

```
id      offer_id        pic_name        pic_type
1       105             dog1            .jpg
2       105             dog2            .jpg
3       105             dog3            .jpg
```

So the question is how I can call all pictures from table 2 with ID 105

I tried this, but I can get only one picture..

func.php

```
function getPicsById($offer_id,$link){


$query = "SELECT * from `offers_pics` where `offer_id` = '$offer_id';";
$res = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$resul = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

return $resul;

}
```

offer.php

```
$result_pic = getPicsById($offer_id,$link);
                echo $result_pic['pic_name'];
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Warning: Your code is open to SQL injection attacks.  You should take a look at prepared statements and query parameters.  Basically, values should be treated as *values* and not as *executable code*.

Comment: Start off with the question. This is difficult to understand.

Comment: Your function returns one row. You wanted [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) I guess. I will be an array, so echo won't work - need to iterate.